# Проблемы с коллайдерами в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Код на камере

```
private Ray ray;
private RaycastHit hit;
private Vector3 rot = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

void Update()
{


    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.CompareTag("fishka"))
        {
            Collider col = hit.collider;

            rot.z = hit.point.z;
            rot.x = hit.point.x;
            col.attachedRigidbody.MovePosition(rot);
```

Выглядит оно в итоге вот так - rigidbody дергаются, потом проходят друг через друга. Иногда. Как можно этого избежать?

https://youtu.be/2q01fKFwLG4

Comment: проблема не раскрыта, видео не работает.

Comment: @ValeraKvip сделал доступ по ссылке, прошу прощения. Проверяйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри внимательно документацию
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html 
Они используют Time.deltaTime для регуляции скорости (и вообще какую нибудь константу )

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
```

А проходят друг через друга наверно по той же причине что они перемещаются быстрей чем столкновение может быть определенно.

Comment: в том виде в котором есть проблема осталась. Видео сделал с нормальным доступом

Comment: если это игра " пятнашки", то подход к реализации так себе (ужасный даже). Я запустил у себя дерганость из-за interpolate. Ну и вообще что это должно быть?

Comment: Без interpolate оно наезжает друг на друга и проходит чаще. C interpolate дергается, но проникает менее часто. 

Да, пятнашки с использованием физики. Чтоб было полное ощущение что таскаешь обычные кубики. Через код знаю как сделать, построил сетку, массив и работай, а вот хотелось бы именно физическую симуляцию настоящих пятнашек

Comment: Проблема, как ты справедливо заметил, в скорости. Вернее, в неумолимости MoveTo. Можно было бы как нибудь сделать вместо MoveTo, чтобы кубик к курсору мышки устремлялся с некой силой. Т.е. сделать AddForce к некой точке, смесь AddForce и MoveTo.
И сила это не такая большая,чтобы ускорять тело настолько, чтобы оно пробивало другие коллайдеры.

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто! Вы используете не физику для движения, а простое значение `Transform` у rb объектов. Таким образом вы говорите кубику, двигаться, игнорируя все(или почти все).
Поясняю, физика, во всем, это не только привычные 3 координаты (X,Y,Z), но и 4 вектор время.

Сделайте следующим образом:

```
col.attachedRigidbody.MovePosition(rot)*speed*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

А вообще, по таким вопросам, вам бы писать скорее [на русское сообщество](http://Unity3d.ru/)
или [в группы по Unity в вк](https://vk.com/unity3d_gamedev).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй поиграться с масштабом. При меньших размерах коллайдеров и меньшем расстоянии между ними, или наоборот при больших, во многих физ движках лаги разные.